# centos 6 oid information for net-snmp

Tags: nagios, snmp, centos6, oid

I am trying to set up nagios core 3 to monitor linux servers using net-snmp, having trouble to find the correct oids for snmp.

mibDepot.com seems to be a good site, but I tried most of them, not working...
Any suggestions where to look?

Thanks!

Comment: [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) might be better suited for your needs. Nagios is not good at requesting several pieces of information via snmp. Only **check_mk** is a try to get that into a single request.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the **snmpd** installed on your Nagios server (running CentOS 6?) everything is already in place. Then you can start monitoring using the OID-names as well.

Do a `snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $TARGETSYS` to dump a full snmp-listing of the target system.

Comment: Thanks, Nil. I tried with snmpwalk and snmpbulkwalk, the output are similar. I am looking for oids for disk, mem, cpu, etc. but can't seem find them. Am I missing something on the client?

Comment: If you can only "see" the system-OIDs you propably have limited access to the client with your community-string. What client is that? CentOS6, too?

Comment: centos 5.7, but I tried with localhost (centos 6) as well, still only see limited oids.

Comment: @Linux the default snmpd.conf is very restrictive on CentOS. use a different community (i.e. define one on the client) to get all data. If you look at the file there are already some examples in place. The combination of the source-IP (i.e. the Nagios server) and the community string will identify which security set is to be applied to the snmp-query. The default "public" will restrict you to the system "view".

Answer (score 0):

SNMP is good for network devices. For centos systems look at the nrpe daemon and client.

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf

Comment: Sorry - SNMP is the standard to monitor almost any device. Look at **OpenNMS** and its usage...

Comment: Nils.. I've written custom MIB files. I'm familiar with SNMP. It doesn't change the fact that there are better options out there for a lot of devices. There are certain stats that are a pain in the butt if not impossible to get with SNMP.

Comment: If you can afford the resources to build monitoring methods for each OS - ok. But an additional daemon or agent? Why when there are snmpd and sshd already running?

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I am hope to get all the monitoring done for network devices and linux servers in snmp instead of using both snmp and nrpe. It might be hard to find more plugins for snmp since there are more for nrpe, that's only downside I've heard. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you're trying to do, but I'd start w/ nagios-plugins:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ rpm -q nagios-plugins
nagios-plugins-1.4.15-2.el6.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

then you can use following plugin to make snmp calls

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp 
check_snmp: Could not parse arguments
Usage:
check_snmp -H <ip_address> -o <OID> [-w warn_range] [-c crit_range]
[-C community] [-s string] [-r regex] [-R regexi] [-t timeout] [-e retries]
[-l label] [-u units] [-p port-number] [-d delimiter] [-D output-delimiter]
[-m miblist] [-P snmp version] [-L seclevel] [-U secname] [-a authproto]
[-A authpasswd] [-x privproto] [-X privpasswd]
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

I usually start from snmpwalk and then find right oid to check and take it to check_snmp nagios's plugin.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I've done that part, trying to find the oids so I can monitoring centos 6 servers via net-snmp.